# Extracting values from raw table

Tags: swift

I get a table `lensDistortionLookupTable` which is a NSData of floats of  from [AVCalibrationData](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avdepthdata/2881230-cameracalibrationdata) and want to cast it into an array. What's the
right way to do it with Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. get the bytes from the `Data`  with `withUnsafeBytes`
2. use it to create a `UnsafeBufferPointer` of `Float32` (according to the doc)
3. cast it to a regular `Array`

   ```
   let float32size = MemoryLayout<Float32>.stride // should be 4, but do not hardcode
   let elementCount = data.count / float32Size

   let table: [Float32] = depthData.cameraCalibrationData!.lensDistortionLookupTable.withUnsafeBytes {
                      return Array(UnsafeBufferPointer<Float32>(start: $0, count: elementCount))
                   }
   ```